# Down and UP arrow keys not scrolling the current cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a `windows form` which contains two controls `Textbox` and `Datagridview`.

Now when I first open the form the focus should be on textbox and if I type something it should be appended in textbox.

And if I press the `UP/Down arrow key` focus should be on `DataGridview` and the `Highlight` should move to the next row.

But the problem is it only set the focus to `gridview` but doesn't select the next row. It scrolls `down/UP on next key press`. Same if focus is on the `GridView` and `if I start typing alphabets it should be appended to TextBox text`, but here also it sets only focus to `textbox` and on another key press it starts typing text in it.

How to implement this?

Code which I am using is:

```
 if (e.KeyCode== Keys.Down)
            {
                this.DgAppDetails.Focus();
                int index = DgAppDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (index != DgAppDetails.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        DgAppDetails.CurrentCell = DgAppDetails.Rows[index+1].Cells[0];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Up)
            {
                this.DgAppDetails.Focus();
                int index = DgAppDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (index != 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                      DgAppDetails.CurrentCell = DgAppDetails.Rows[index - 1].Cells[0];
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: do you have example of the Code..? also are you setting anything like the `control.Focus()?` [MSDN Control.Focus() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) also what events are you using in regards to typing in the DataGridView..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing, is because you're changing the `CurrentCell`, **not** however, the `SelectedCells`

Try this:

```
DgAppDetails.SelectedCells.Clear();
DgAppDetails.SelectedCells.Insert(DgAppDetails.CurrentCell);
```